# Show that $Y_1[t]- Y_2[t] \to 0$ as long as $t \to \infty$ - Differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Let the differential equation $L[y] = a y'' + by' + cy = g(t)$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are strictly positive numbers. If $Y_1(t)$ and $Y_2(t)$ are solutions at the $L[y]$ equation, show that $Y_1[t]- Y_2[t] \to 0$ as long as $t \to \infty$.

I know that $Y_1[t]- Y_2[t]$ has to be a solution of $L[y] =0$. I  think I have to use the discriminant $b^2-4ac > 0$. However, it's not clear that $b^2 > 4ac$.

Is anyone could give me a good hint?

Comment: Why did you remove the previous question?

Comment: Your previous question had a perfectly good hint.

Comment: Can you post the solutions $Y_1,Y_2$?

Comment: There is no explicite formulas for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. This is a theric question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that the solution $Y$ of $L[y]=0$ tends to $0$ as $t$ goes to infinity.

Note that $ay''+by'+cy=0$ has characteristic equation $ar^2+br+c=0$. Since $a,b,c$ are positive numbers, the solutions $r=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ have negative real part.

So the solution is either $Y(t)=C_1e^{\alpha t}+C_2e^{\beta t}$ (with $\alpha, \beta<0$), or

$Y(t)=C_1e^{\alpha t}\cos(\beta t)+C_2e^{\alpha t}\sin(\beta t)$ with $\alpha<0$.

In both cases since the powers of exponential are negative, as $t$ goes to infinity we would have $Y(t)$ goes to $0$.

Comment: i forgot about the case when there is one root, but in this case you can show that the limit of $te^{at}$ is zero as $t$ is infinite